# How to make a Container fit to the Text length

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-container

I have a Container with maximum width and I dont want to have additional free space after words. It works fine with small words like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCgyS.png) .
But with long words i have additional free space and my line looks
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCVPZ.png) . What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: size.width * 0.4),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.015),
                //color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  "Generics",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to help without your full Row code, but I'd first take a look at dart debug tools and apply debug paint. That might give some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `FittedBox`. It will make sure that it's children have the given `fit`.

Here is an example from flutter.dev:

```
Widget build(BuildContext) {
  return Container(
    height: 400,
    width: 300,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: FittedBox(
      child: Image.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
  );
}
```

Read more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  Unfortunally I tried this and i got this https://ibb.co/qsXjQMD
Maybe you know what to do?